# DBCPConnectionPoolLookup complaining about missing database.name even when it is set

Tags: apache-nifi

We are finding this behaviour on NiFi 1.8.0.
As you can see by the pictures, the flowfiles have the attribute set (both by visual inspection and by being passed through a RouteByAttributes that checks `${database.name:isEmpty():not()}`

We also tried removing the attribute and adding it explicitly again, but the behaviour still holds.
Please note that we are using the `DBCPConnectionPoolLookup`+`database.name` mechanism successfully in other parts of the diagram.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot or what to look for?

Thanks

[image: PutSQL immediately after checking for the attribute]
[image: Attribute exists when inspecting flowfiles in the queue]
[image: Error message]

Comment: No pictures are showing

Comment: Thx. Just fixed it

Comment: As a test, could you try changing the Batch Size in PutSQL to 1 and see if the error goes away? I know that would degrade performance, but just want to see if that is related to the issue as I think I see an issue in the code related to that

Comment: I can try. I currently is set to 500, with "support fragmented transactions"==false and no "rollback on failure"

Comment: Yes. with BatchSize==1 it  works. Great hint!. Any workarounds? Thx

Comment: We will have to look into, but I'm not sure we can support the lookup approach with batch size > 1, currently it gets a connection for the whole batch, but when you are using the lookup approach it would have to get a connection per each flow file in the batch, because each flow file could have a different database.name

Comment: Created this JIRA for the issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5970